# When to choose "with doing this" or "by doing this"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, by-with

> Governments should enact laws to restrict drivers' behaviors in some areas...........
>
> 1. With doing this, we can create a safer community.
> 2. By doing this, we can create a safer community.

Which one is correct and formally suitable to writing?

Comment: Not "with". Without a preposition at all is better than "with" here.

Answer (score 1):

Very roughly:

by is correct. by, in this case, indicates the "how" something is done. i.e. we can create a safer community. How? by doing this.

with has many meanings none of which really fit here. They mostly describe a process or entity that is being done together with another process or entity.

Comment: It helps a lot. According to your comment, can I write this? With taking a umbrella, you can avoid getting wet if it rains.

Comment: no: **how** can you get avoid getting wet? by taking an umbrella

Comment: Oh, I understand it now. However, there are two sentences. Can I write like this to combine them into one? Taking an umbrella if you leave home, you can avoid getting wet if it rains.

Comment: yes: (By) taking an umbrella when you leave home, you can avoid getting wet if it rains. "by" here is optional but implied.

Comment: In the UK, we refer to laws as being 'passed', and While I appreciate the underlying assumption that the rule of law tends to a more regulated community, there are questions that arise about the assumed justice of a particular law, or the limitation to safety - many draconian laws are passed in Russia at the moment, to cite just one example. Others have to do with health, wellbeing, education, etc.

Comment: 'With' _could_ be used in a paraphrase: With this course of action, we can create a safer community. // We can create a safer community with this course of action. (Here, 'with' = 'by employing'.)